# what does -s option mean in GNU sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have read the [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) manual for the `-s` option. There it says:

> -s
>   --separate By default, sed will consider the files specified on the command line as a single continuous long stream. This GNU sed
>   extension allows the user to consider them as separate files: range
>   addresses (such as ‘/abc/,/def/’) are not allowed to span several
>   files, line numbers are relative to the start of each file, $ refers
>   to the last line of each file, and files invoked from the R commands
>   are rewound at the start of each file.

add -s and no -s in the same

```
[root@kvm ~]# cat 1 |sed -s   -n '/1/p'
12345a6789a99999a
12345a6789a99999b

[root@kvm ~]# cat 1 |sed     -n '/1/p'
12345a6789a99999a
12345a6789a99999b

1 file is 
cat 1
12345a6789a99999a
12345a6789a99999b
```

How to use -s ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It only matters if you give `sed` multiple files.

If you don't specify the `-s` flag, `sed` will act as if the files contents had been concatenated in a single stream :

```
echo "123
456
789" > file1
echo "abc
def
ghi" > file2

# input files are considered a single stream of 6 lines, whose second to fourth are printed
sed -n '2,4 p' file1 file2 

456    # stream 1, line 2
789    # stream 1, line 3
abc    # stream 1, line 4


# there are two distinct streams of 3 lines the 2nd and 3rd of each are printed
sed -ns '2,4 p' file1 file2

456    # stream 1, line 2
789    # stream 1, line 3
def    # stream 2, line 2
ghi    # stream 2, line 3
```

Comment: Nice example selection and great explanation

Comment: could you also explain how to do multi-line, please?

Comment: @tatsu I'm not sure what you're talking about, but I don't see how it could be relevant to the description of `sed`'s `-s` flag. I think you will want to search for a more relevant question or ask your own.